# Storing external data in Nook devices

Tags: android, storage, nook

How to store data in Nook device (emulator) without SD card. or how to use /media in Nook device (emulator).

Comment: I never did figure out how to get at /media, though I can write to /data. Here's my question and answer (with sample code) http://stackoverflow.com/a/7863090/597849.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse

go to DDMS perspective and select the FileExplorer tab in that select a sd card 
after selecting sd card you see the two icon for push file on to device and pull file from the device

Comment: we don't want to use any sd card i want to use media folder of the Nook devices to store my content(data) .any example will be appreciated.